# Most effective defense constructions in Die2Nite

Tags: die2nite

What are the most effective ways (most defense points per AP/materials) to increase the town defense in Die2Nite? Which buildings are important for long-term defense development?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the optimal construction strategy in die2nite?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11765/whats-the-optimal-construction-strategy-in-die2nite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you go ballistic on the wiki and the tables, be aware that many constructions can and *should* be upgraded, so comparing their base values may be misleading.

**Defensive focus**, for example, doesn't net you any instrinsic defense. However, it brings more value from your defensive items. The first level gives you .5 extra defense per item (which was +23 def for us!), and the bonus increases with every following upgrade (level 5 gets you +8 def/item instead of +2).

**Upgradeable wall** is another good example of this. Level 1 is a mere 15 defense, but level 2 gets you *51* defense, and it only goes up with each upgrade.

Comment: http://die2nite.wikia.com/wiki/Town_Upgrades
DF:2.5>3.2>4.4>5.6>6.8>8
UW:15>51>86>123>182>243

Answer (score 2):

Some specific numbers around how to spend your daily upgrades:

- 5 days of Pit upgrades grants +150 DEF
- 5 days of Wall upgrades grants +228 DEF
- 5 days of Defensive Focus upgrades grants 8 DEF per defensive object (as opposed to the 2 DEF per object you get by default)

If you have more than 25 defensive objects (200 DEF, a net gain of +150 over default), 5xDefensive Focus is a more attractive upgrade than the 5xPit Upgrade (but still not as attractive as 5xWall).

If you have more than 34 defensive objects (272 DEF, a net gain of +228 DEF), then 5xDefensive Focus is even more valuable than 5xWall. (and it can keep getting better and better, as in Robinhood/Badp's example).

Answer (score 0):

Defensive Focus is epic.  My (and Badp's) town have 52 defensive items right now.  That equates to 312 extra defense after 5 days of upgrade, and we're bound to find more in 4 days.  It's a very good construction project if you have a lot of defensive items.